# Duplicate Symbol Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm not sure what I did but I added an IBOutlet to display an additional attribute in a TableView cell. When building the application I get the following error message...

```
Ld /Users/roberthill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PHAInspect-awfhtfopjdgfmsdsjfjivdnlzgir/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PHAInspect.app/PHAInspect normal i386
    cd /Users/roberthill/Documents/PHAInspect
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/roberthill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PHAInspect-awfhtfopjdgfmsdsjfjivdnlzgir/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/roberthill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PHAInspect-awfhtfopjdgfmsdsjfjivdnlzgir/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/roberthill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PHAInspect-awfhtfopjdgfmsdsjfjivdnlzgir/Build/Intermediates/PHAInspect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PHAInspect.build/Objects-normal/i386/PHAInspect.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -framework CoreData -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/roberthill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PHAInspect-awfhtfopjdgfmsdsjfjivdnlzgir/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PHAInspect.app/PHAInspect

ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Inspection in /Users/roberthill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PHAInspect-awfhtfopjdgfmsdsjfjivdnlzgir/Build/Intermediates/PHAInspect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PHAInspect.build/Objects-normal/i386/Inspection-AEDA73D75B42426A.o and /Users/roberthill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PHAInspect-awfhtfopjdgfmsdsjfjivdnlzgir/Build/Intermediates/PHAInspect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PHAInspect.build/Objects-normal/i386/Inspection-AEDA73D75B42426A.o for architecture i386
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I tried backing out the changes to add the IBOutlet but I'm still getting this error message.

I checked other similar posts but I don't think the conditions are the same (I could be wrong though). Any ideas?

Comment: I ran into something like t his before. If you perform a clean and it doesn't resolve the issue try clearing away your derived data. To clear out your derived data go to Organizer -> Project -> Delete button for derived data.

Answer (score 51):

I had a similar issue:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MyClass1 in /Users/.../MyClass2.o and /Users/.../MyClass1.o for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And finally the reason was that inside MyClass2.m I wrote:

```
#include "MyClass1.m"
```

Instead of

```
#include "MyClass1.h"
```

It's hard to find when you have a lot of #include statements inside your .m file.

Comment: Perfect...  Such a simple mistake to make.  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Shame on me... Got same typo

Comment: Feel like such a newb when I do this... Thanks for the answer =)

Answer (score 20):

This can happen when a source is compiled in your target twice, or if it is built in two separate targets. You can verify this in your target's build phases, or remove it from the target and then re-add it.

**Update**

Kasas pointed out a new Xcode feature (in an Edit which other reviewers rejected), where Xcode can detect some such cases for you -- Simply "Validate" the target or project settings. If found, Xcode will offer to remove the redundant compilation for you. Thanks Kasas.

Answer (score 11):

Other than the .m issue, if you created models in the wrong folder, deleted them and then created/replaced the models in the correct folder.  You may need to remove the duplicates in Targets **Build Phases** under the **Compiled Sources** grouping.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem . I solve it.

Because ı did mistake when ı import to viewcontroller .

mistake:     #import "viewcontroller.**m**"

Later I edit : `#import "viewcontroller.**h**"

only I changed extension of viewcontroller .

Answer (score 2):

In my first app, I had this problem after replacing a class. As I didn't want to delete the old class completely, I moved it to another group, still within xcode. xcode tries to compile two copies of this class, causing the error. Deleting the references to the old class from the project fixed my problem.

Upvote went to quarac, who made this easier for me to spot.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but a silly question - did you do a clean after clearing the old code? Sometimes that stuff hangs around.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a "clean".

Comment: Menus: Product - Clean. It removes all the temporary build directories. This is useful when you have deleted things from the code base because sometimes compiled objects are still in the temp build directories and get "accidentally" included even though your source no longer has them. This can be a source of unexpected errors like this. It won't hurt anything so you might as well be sure.

Answer (score 1):

If more than one class shares a ***same name*** this kind of error will come

Answer (score 0):

This might b due to the reason that you have included two source files of `Inspection` class

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand why this would be a problem so maybe someone could clarify but for me the problem was that I had **imported** another class which had declared an **instance variable with the same name** as one in the current class.

When I changed the name of the ivar in the imported class's implementation the error disappeared.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This may happen also if you have constant definitions with the same name in two different classes. In my case it was a boolean flag like these:

Class A:

```
#import "MyATableViewController.h"

@implementation MyATableViewController

@synthesize someVariable;

BOOL MY_FLAG = YES;
...
```

Class B:

```
#import "MyBTableViewController.h"

@implementation MyBTableViewController

@synthesize someVariable;

BOOL MY_FLAG = YES;
...
```

I just had to change the constant definition on the second class to:

```
... BOOL MY_B_FLAG = YES; ...
```

Answer (score 0):

i had meet same problem, and i solved it.
When i copy and paste my view and  view controller with different name, i got this error (dublicate sembol in _temp). i solved this error by changing constant name. You can also move your constant between implemantation bracets. My examples code below. And my constant name is temp.

```
    @implementation MyCombineSaveTableView
{
    BOOL *pulltoRefResh;
    NSString *currentElement;
    int temp;
    int User_ID;
}
```