# iOS Simulator launch fails, app launches fine on iPhone

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, linker-errors, duplicate-symbol

I'm getting a Mach-O Linker error when trying to launch an app (which launches without problems on an iPhone 4S) on the iOS simulator.

Error:

ld: 224 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm puzzled both by the duplicate symbols error, and the fact that this only seems to be a problem on the simulator.

Comment: First move should be to quit and clean out the Derived Data folder, just to make sure this isn't a momentary glitch.

Comment: Then try some of the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169944/duplicate-symbol-error

Comment: Thanks, Matt. Did both. What I don't get is why any duplicates I may have added by mistake - the bulk of the explanations offered in that thread - should cause the build to fail on the simulator only - the real devices are perfectly happy. Is there a shortcut to finding duplicates in Xcode?

Comment: "What I don't get is why [this] should cause the build to fail on the simulator only" I think it's because you only made this mistake for one architecture (i386), which is the Simulator architecture. See e.g. this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13230888/341994